# Magento 1.9 Override Model Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, model

Path File i want Override
app\code\community\OtherCompany\core\Model\Api\Rest\Client.php

Path my file override
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Api\Rest\Client.php

app\etc\modules\MyCompany_MyModule.xml  After change

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <OtherCompany_Payments/>
                <OtherCompany_Core/>
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
            <rewrite>
               <api>
                  <rest>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Api_Rest_Client</rest>
               </api>
            </rewrite>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

My File path:
app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Api\Rest\Client.php

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Api_Rest_Client extends OtherCompany_Core_Model_Api_Rest_Client  {

protected function _construct() 
{
    highlight_string(print_r('_construct',true));
    exit();
} }
```

are the declared routes correct?
or it may depend on the etc \ module file

where  is specified
I should write 
or

and in case the code depends on 
is compromised if I write only ?

Comment: Can you add config.xml from `Other`Company` module?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you add config.xml from the module that you want to rewrite?

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo did u see my answer ?

Comment: yes, I delayed answering, sorry. then it worked, but between one problem and another, only today I managed to get back on the forum

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo plz mark it as correct + vote thanks

Comment: Done! have vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know if works

```
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
        </mymodule>
        <mymodule_api_rest>
          <rewrite>      
             <client>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Api_Rest_Client</client>
          </rewrite>
        </mymodule_api_rest>
    </models>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the `config.xml` that you've written. You generally would define your own model namespace "mymodule", then another node for the namespace you're rewriting ("api"), and put your rewrite in there. See below:

```
...
<models>
    <mymodule>
        <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
    </mymodule>
    <api>
        <rewrite>
            <rest>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Api_Rest_Client</rest>
        </rewrite>
    </api>
</models>
...
```

Comment: Your own model declaration is wrong.

Comment: Hi @sv3n, thanks for pointing that out! Stupid mistake when copying it out on my part... I've edited and should have corrected this now. Hope it works!

Comment: thanks for the tip but it does not work